# HTML Text not showing over Image

Tags: html, css

My text/header is not showing over my image which I'm trying to use as a background to this webpage. This is the code I have right now:

```
HTML:

<body id="body">

    <div id="navbar">
         <h1 id="name">Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <img class="backgroundimg" src="leaf.jpg" alt="A leaf"/>

    </div>


    <div class="backimg">
    <img class="backgroundimg" src="buildings.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="backimg">
    <img class="backgroundimg" src="squares.jpg"/>
    </div>

</body>

CSS:

 body {
    background-color:black
}


 backgroundimg {
    position:relative;
    width:1175px;

}

 name {
    position:absolute;
    color: white;
    z-index;
}
```

Any tips?
P.S. I took out the '#' and '.' to the appropriate names in CSS.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Thank you for that link, got it.

Answer (score 7):

Use z-index to show the text over image.

Comment: So i put z-index in the CSS. It now recognizes a text box in a live preview but doesn't show any text.

Comment: No, the text color is white, and the image is green. When I play with the code and purposely mess it up, then the text will come over the an extremely blurred and too large version of the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use z-index, like Anil Panwar said(https://stackoverflow.com/a/34374513/4900669)

```
#name {
   position:absolute;
   color: white;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/08voh0fp/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file

```
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

adjust top,left and width according your need,
let me know if this helped