# Descriptions of all images appear when a single image is enlarged

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in the process of making a very simple image gallery with descriptions, which enlarges an image when it's clicked.

The problem I'm running into is that when an image is clicked, then **all** description boxes are displayed all over as opposed to just the clicked image and its description below the image.

Here is my code snippet so far:

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery img');

function toggleEnlarged(event) {
  const image = event.target;
  if (image.classList.contains('enlarged')) {
    image.classList.remove('enlarged');
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      images[i].classList.remove('enlarged');
    }
    image.classList.add('enlarged');
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].addEventListener('click', toggleEnlarged);
}
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.gallery .image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery img.enlarged {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  object-fit: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 10px solid white;
  background-color: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery .image-container p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: rgba(1, 20, 50, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 999;
}

.gallery .image-container:hover p {
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=1" alt="Image 1">
    <p>Description of Image 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=2" alt="Image 2">
    <p>Description of Image 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=3" alt="Image 3">
    <p>Description of Image 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from this code, when you click on an image to enlarge it, then the description boxes from the other images appear when they should not.

I have tried this answer:  [Can’t get the text to appear below the Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920049/can-t-get-the-text-to-appear-below-the-image), but it didn't pertain to enlarging the image, and only its description showing.

I looked here:  [CSS Show Image Title below image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74749160/css-show-image-title-below-image), this again doesn't have to do with enlarging the image and showing just its description, but rather just presenting an image and its caption.

I have tried this:  [HTML Text not showing over Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374497/html-text-not-showing-over-image) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index by adding the following property `z-index: 999;` to `.gallery img.enlarged`, and although it actually displayed the descriptions - the descriptions of all images are displayed when it should just be the image enlarged.

Can I get some guidance of what I should do to only display the description below the image of **only** the enlarged image?

Comment: FYI, I edited your example to include real links to working images.  Your question didn't really make sense without them

Comment: I think it would make a lot more sense you put the `enlarged` class on `.image-container` instead of directly on the `<img` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting `z-index: 999` on ALL `p` tags.  You only need to set this when it has the `enlarged` class.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery img');

function toggleEnlarged(event) {
  const image = event.target;
  if (image.classList.contains('enlarged')) {
    image.classList.remove('enlarged');
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      images[i].classList.remove('enlarged');
    }
    image.classList.add('enlarged');
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].addEventListener('click', toggleEnlarged);
}
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.gallery .image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery img.enlarged {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  object-fit: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 10px solid white;
  background-color: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*ADDED*/
.gallery img.enlarged + p {
  z-index: 999; 
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.gallery .image-container p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: rgba(1, 20, 50, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
  /*z-index: 999;*/ /*REMOVED*/
}

.gallery .image-container:hover p {
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=1" alt="Image 1">
    <p>Description of Image 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=2" alt="Image 2">
    <p>Description of Image 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=3" alt="Image 3">
    <p>Description of Image 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for the description of the enlarged image to also be displayed under it:  "Can I get some guidance of what I should do to **only display the description below the image of only the enlarged image**?" This code you provided removes ALL descriptions when any image is clicked on.  They're initial code shows all the other descriptions when an image is clicked on.

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I've fixed it now to show only the text for the selected image and not the others

Answer (score 1):

If you add the "enlarged" class to the image container, things get a little easier. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're going for, but it should be closer.

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery .image-container');

function toggleEnlarged(event) {
  const container = event.currentTarget;
  if (container.classList.contains('enlarged')) {
    container.classList.remove('enlarged');
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
      containers[i].classList.remove('enlarged');
    }
    container.classList.add('enlarged');
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  containers[i].addEventListener('click', toggleEnlarged);
}
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.gallery .image-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.gallery .image-container.enlarged {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.gallery .image-container.enlarged img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 10px solid white;
  background-color: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery .image-container p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: rgba(1, 20, 50, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.gallery .image-container:hover p,
.gallery .image-container.enlarged p {
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=1" alt="Image 1">
    <p>Description of Image 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=2" alt="Image 2">
    <p>Description of Image 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=3" alt="Image 3">
    <p>Description of Image 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```